# Esta aparecendo essa mensagem de erro quando executo meu programa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ao executar meu programa surge o seguinte erro:

```
>Error  1   'AgendaMVC.Models.AgendaDBContext' does not contain a definition
```

`for 'Agenda' and no extension method 'Agenda' accepting a first argument
 of type` `'AgendaMVC.Models.AgendaDBContext' could be found (are you missing a` `using directive or an assembly reference?)`

```
C:\curso\Agenda\Agenda\Controllers\AgendaController.cs  33  35  Agenda
```

o que pode ser?

**********classe agendaDBContext*******************

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Data.Entity; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Web; 
using AgendaMVC.Models;

namespace AgendaMVC.Models 
{ 
    public class AgendaDBContext : DbContext 
    {    
        public AgendaDBContext() :base("name=AgendaDBContext")
        {

        } 

        DbSet Agendas { get; set; } 
    } 
}
```

---

Controller:

```
using AgendaMVC.Models;
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AgendaMVC.Controllers
{
    public class AgendaController : Controller
    {
       AgendaDBContext agendaContext = new AgendaDBContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Inserir() 
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Inserir(Agenda agenda) 
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) 
            {
                try
                {
                    agendaContext.Agenda.Add(agenda);//o problema esta aqui agendaContext //nao reconhece a agenda
                    agendaContext.SaveChanges();

                    return Json(new
                    {
                        Url = Url.Action("Index"),
                        Mensagem = "Contato Inserido com sucesso",
                        Titulo = "Sucesso"
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception) {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return View(agenda);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: informe seu contexto, o erro, a dúvida e suas pesquisas por favor.

Comment: esse eh o erro que aparece o que pode ser?

Comment: Poste o código de C:\curso\Agenda\Agenda\Controllers\AgendaController.cs

Comment: nao, você não ententeu.
na pergunta vc deve colocar o contexto!
ou seja, explique o que seu programa faz, coloque o erro apresentado, e o trecho de código aonde vc acha que tem o erro. 
tipo assim: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39511/problema-com-conex%C3%A3o-ftp-no-android

Comment: como eu faco, pois quando faço excede o limite

Comment: não no comentário, edite sua pergunta(abaixo das tags entre compartilhar e sinalizar)

Comment: using AgendaMVC.Models;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace AgendaMVC.Controllers
{
public class AgendaController : Controller
{
AgendaDBContext agendaContext = new AgendaDBContext();
public ActionResult Inserir() 
{
return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Inserir(Agenda agenda) 
{
if(ModelState.IsValid) 
{
try
{
  agendaContext.Agenda.Add(agenda);
  agendaContext.SaveChanges();
 return Json(new
  {
  Url = Url.Action("Index"),
 Mensagem = "Contato Inserido com sucesso",
 Titulo = "Sucesso"
 });
}
catch (Exception) {
throw;
}
}
return View(agenda);
 }
 }
}

Comment: @EversonSouzadeAraujo Você pode alterar a pergunta e incluir o código da classe AgendaDBContext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baseado no que consegui deduzir da sua classe "AgendaDBContext" o problema é que a variável Agenda não é pública.

Em C#, quando o modificador de acesso é omitido, private é inferido. Ou seja, quando você faz:

```
DbSet Agendas { get; set; }
```

Significa que essa variável é visível somente dentro da classe AgendaDBContext.

Para resolver o problema, inclua o modificador public:

```
namespace AgendaMVC.Models 
{ 
    public class AgendaDBContext : DbContext 
    {    
        public AgendaDBContext() :base("name=AgendaDBContext")
        {
        } 
        public DbSet Agendas { get; set; } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: show deu certo, não me atentei para esse detalhe

Comment: @EversonSouzadeAraujo Legal. Já que a solução funcionou, o ideal é que você marque-a como resposta certa.

Comment: eh a primeira vez que uso esse forum ainda nao sei, como eu faço?

Comment: @EversonSouzadeAraujo Segue o link explicando: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour. No canto esquerdo da minha resposta existe setas para cima e para baixo, entre elas está um número que indica se a resposta é útil ou não, se você acha que a resposta é útil você marca pra cima e claro faz o contrário quando a mesma não é. Para marcar a resposta como aceita você clica no check cinza logo abaixo desse controle. O mesmo passará para verde indicando a resposta escolhida como correta.

Comment: Leitura Complementar: [Referência do MS sobre padrões dos Modificadores de acessos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)

Comment: obrigado @AndreFigueiredo